# How can I get response time below 200ms taken by google places API?

Tags: java, json, google-places-api, postman, newrelic

I am using below google places api-

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=28.4369350,77.1125600&radius=5000&types=atm&name=hdfc&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I am getting response from it in 1-2 sec using postman and 700ms for 1500 API hits from new relic. Is there anyway to get it below 200ms?

Comment: This highly depends on your internet connection. What kind of connection do you have? Which speed does it allow?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for this late reply @dunni. Using Spectranet with 5 mbps speed